# How to open new tab using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, tabs

How to open new tab and in the new tab the Google Maps site would display in Javascript?
Please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myFunc(url) {
  var x = window.open(url, '_blank');
  x.focus();
}
```

Comment: Is just all I need just to open a new tab?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open('https://maps.google.com', '_blank');
```

Please search before ask a question.